# Oracle SQL Developer changing date format when exporting

Tags: database, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel

I am using Oracle SQL Developer **Version 19.2.1.247**

The data in my database look like this:

[image]

My Database: NLS settings look like this:

[image]

When I export the data, I do the following:

[image]

When I open the excel file, it looks like this:

[image]

Why not return dates in the same format as in the database? It worked before, but now, for some reason, it's not the case anymore.

Comment: pretty sure that's Excel, not SQL Developer. Change the date format to CSV, then open it in a text editor and then again in Excel and compare.

Comment: I switched from version 4.0.3.16 to 19.2.1.247. However, everything else stayed the same. It worked with Excel that's why I think it has something to do with SQL Developer. @thatjeffsmith

Comment: 19.2 is setup to export date fields AS dates in the Excel cells - that's the diff between 4.0.3 and 19.2

Comment: There must be a way to perform this action with 19.2. @thatjeffsmith

Comment: Where did you get that information? Can you send a link? Thanks. @thatjeffsmith

Comment: here https://www.oracle.com//technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-relnotes-192-5592849.html

Answer (score 1):

The key to understand the problems is on: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldev/sqldev-relnotes-v192.html

The release note: Data Export: Excel exports format DATES as DATES

You can downgrade to an older version of sqldeveloper or prey to this get adjusted to excel exports format dates as you config on sqldeveloper on future.

Answer (score 0):

This is excel showing you ###### when there is not enough space to show the data. Expand the column width and you should be able to see the data normally.

Comment: That's not the only problem. The day and month are shown in mm.dd.yyyy US format. For me the dates show as "6.30.2017" which is a hodgepodge of US and Finnish date formats. Finnish date format is dd.mm.yyyy. The columns in excel use "Custom" format and have to be converted manually to "Short Date" to show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer's dialog export wizard, select "csv" from comboBox "Format:" and complete the export.
In MS Excel go to tab "Data" and select "from text/CSV", select your export.csv and complete the import.